# Is there any plugin that helps correcting gramatical issues in Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf, text, grammar

I'm using Overleaf to write a book, I wonder if there is a package or plugin to add to the online version to correct all grammatical issues ?

Comment: As this is an Overleaf question, not a LaTeX question, it would be best to direct it to Overleaf support: support@overleaf.com. I'm on the support team there, and can assure you that we are happy to receive these kinds of questions :) FYI: there is an Overleaf language Chrome extension provided by our friends at https://writefull.com/.

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot will reach out to you! didn't think about reaching directly overleaf :)